# Setting ClientID on OracleConnection object via Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, odp.net

In rewriting a web service in C# using Dapper, I need the ability to set the `OracleConnection` object's [ClientID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/ConnectionClientId.htm).) property.  This is used by various triggers in our Oracle database to note the user that modified the data.

Is there any way to access or set this property via Dapper?  I've searched and have come up empty.  I like the convenience of Dapper, but I'm afraid these intricate database-specific settings may not be available to be read or modified.  Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing around a single database connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper just extends off of your `DbConnection`, so there's no need for it to get involved.

You would set the `ClientId` directly on the `OracleConnection`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleConnectionClass.htm#DAFCFAHF

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conectionString))
{
    connection.ClientId = "MyClientId";
    connection.{DapperStuff}();
}
```

Comment: Awesome - being new to Dapper, I just grabbed some example code that was using a generic dbConnection - but I see that the OracleConnection is available.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @motor75 I think using the base `System.Data.Common` classes are ideal in most cases.  However you can always have overrides from a base implementation for specifics like this.